# Using a Count condition in a Case statement to classify a variable

Tags: sql, count, case, vertica

I am trying to count how many times a value occurs in one column, grouped by an ID. Here is an example data set:

```
ID      Yes_or_No
1       Yes
1       No
2       Yes
3       Yes
4       Yes
4       No
5       Yes
```

The general idea is that if I count distinct values for some ID, if the count is greater than one, then I can create a new column that calls it 'Maybe' for instances when some ID takes on both 'Yes' and 'No' values. Here is what I wrote initially, but does not work:

```
SELECT  ID,
        CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT Yes_or_No)>1 AS 'Maybe'
        ELSE Yes_or_No
        END AS YesNoMaybe
FROM db
GROUP BY 1;
```

This is part of a larger overall query, so, ideally, I would like to be able to use the Count within the Case statement as opposed to a subquery in the FROM statement in order to save memory. Other workarounds are welcome.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That query attempt contains product specific stuff.)

Comment: I am using SQL in Vertica.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change `AS` to `THEN`:

```
SELECT  ID,
        CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT Yes_or_No)>1 THEN 'Maybe'
        ELSE MIN(Yes_or_No)    --here agg function is required
        END AS YesNoMaybe
FROM db
GROUP BY ID;   --GROUP BY 1 is antipattern (explicit name >> position)
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=61210fed35f125ec274c1de1639ac356)**

Comment: This works! The use of AS was a sloppy mistake. Another distinction I failed to make was the use of the MIN statement under my ELSE clause.

Answer (score 1):

Your `case` expression should go as

```
SELECT  ID,
        (CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT Yes_or_No) > 1 
              THEN 'Maybe' ELSE MIN(Yes_or_No)
         END) AS YesNoMaybe
FROM db
GROUP BY ID;
```

`As` is not part of `case` expression, it is a part of `select` statement for defining *column* alise or *table* alise